# MyEclipse not deploying link source to WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, myeclipse

I have a web project `web` and a java project `common`.

I set `common`'s source folder as `web`'s link source and used classes in `common` on `web` project without error.

But when I deploy `web` on tomcat, I always get `NoClassDefFoundError` exception. Some classes in `common` are not found. When I check deployed files I find there are only `web`'s classes in `WEB-INF/classes`. But both `common` and `web`'s classes are compiled to default output folder (`web/target/classes`) set in Java Build Path. If I copied all these classes to `WEB-INF/classes`, everything works.

I have checked Deployment Assembly setting but it's already correct. Both `/common`(in `common`) and `/src`(in `web`) are set to Deploy Path `WEB-INF/classes`.

I'm using MyEclipse 10 and tomcat 7.0. How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried letting `common`'s output actually stay in `common` and not trying to wire up the output to combine on your own? You've combined output directories when Deployment Assembly is already prepared to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for the reply but AFAIK when using "link source" all source files are all compiled together just like they are from one project. So the classes should finally be in same output path. Maybe I haven't got your point...

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know why but I switched to another plan and made `common` as a maven package. I imported it into `web` as dependency through maven. Now it works.